# The strange error when deleting the directory

Tags: c#, .net, windows, exception, directory

Windows 7 x64 SP1
.NET Framework 3.5 SP1

I have wrote simple code, but it works through time, the exception occurs at every second pass.
... I.e.: it works fine for the even starts: 2, 4, 6, 8, e.t.c., but I get exception for odd starts: 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, e.t.c.

```
// localMenuDirName is 'GPSM\AdminCAD'.
DirectoryInfo menuDir = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(
    Environment.SpecialFolder.Programs), localMenuDirName));
if (menuDir.Exists) {
    FileInfo[] files = menuDir.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    foreach (FileInfo file in files) {
        file.IsReadOnly = false;
    }
    sb.AppendLine(String.Format("We begin deleting the '{0}' directory", menuDir.FullName));

    Directory.Delete(menuDir.FullName, true); // Get Exception here

    // menuDir.Delete(true); // here I get same exception.
```

Output text:

> We begin deleting the 'C:\Users\andrey.bushman\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start
>   Menu\Programs\GPSM\AdminCAD' directory
>
> Exception: The directory is not empty.

But directory is empty (all files already deleted). I open explorer and see it.

Next code works fine always:

```
// localMenuDirName is 'GPSM\AdminCAD'.
DirectoryInfo menuDir = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(
    Environment.SpecialFolder.Programs), localMenuDirName));
if (menuDir.Exists) {
    FileInfo[] files = menuDir.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    foreach (FileInfo file in files) {
        file.IsReadOnly = false;
    }
    sb.AppendLine(String.Format("We begin deleting the '{0}' directory", menuDir.FullName));

    try {
        Directory.Delete(menuDir.FullName, true); 
    }
    catch {
        // Try again... Now it works without exception!
        Directory.Delete(menuDir.FullName, true);
    }
    sb.AppendLine("Operation was executed successfully.");
```

Why it is happen?

Comment: Do you have a Command Prompt open with the current directory within the directory you are trying to delete?

Comment: maybe you have the directory open in Windows Explorer? Then it cant be deleted, according to the docu: `In some cases, if you have the specified directory open in File Explorer, the Delete method may not be able to delete it.` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62t64db3.aspx

Comment: @leppie No, I run my exe from other directory, and working directory too is other.

Comment: @dognose No, I open directory after exception is occured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different possible options, where the `Directory.Delete` can fail with `IOException`.
According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxeahc5f.aspx)

> A file with the same name and location specified by path exists.
>
> -or- The directory specified by path is read-only, or recursive is false and path is not an empty directory.
>
> -or- The directory is the application's current working directory.
>
> -or- The directory contains a read-only file.
>
> -or- The directory is being used by another process. There is an open handle on the directory or on one of its files, and the operating system is Windows XP or earlier. This open handle can result from enumerating directories and files. For more information, see How to: Enumerate Directories and Files.

In other words: check for open handlers to that *directory*, check for hidden files.

Comment: No, directory not contains hidden files (I created this directory, and I check it). But why my second code work fine???

Comment: @Bush: have no *clear* idea on subject. Just one suspect. Try in your **first** code, inject a delay, just before Directory.Delete. Let's say Thread.Sleep(200). And see if it works like in second case.

Comment: Thank you. It solved my problem. Now works and first variant too (with a pause). But it is interesting for me: why???

Comment: @Bush: don't have **a prove** on this, but I, in my experience too, met different cases when iteratinig over files in directory and *after immediately* deleting directory fails. Cause, I suspect, after itration something remains allocated for some millisecond on IO, which means that, probabbly, this behaviour can vary between different macines too.

Comment: What's is about "When you call Directory.Delete and a file is open in such way, Directory.Delete succeeds in deleting all files but when Directory.Delete calls RemoveDirectory a "directory is not empty" exception is thrown because there is a file marked for deletion but not actually deleted."